# Как получить get параметры из URL в Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Пишу проект на Nuxt есть необходимость получать гет параметры из URL
хочу написать что то типо этого

```
fetch ({store}) {
            let requestPageApi =  axios.get('http://localhost:3005/search/?' + this.$route.query).then((res) => { .....
```

.

**Мой код Nuxt.js**

```
 import axios from "axios";
        export default {
            name: "index",
            fetch ({store}) {
                let requestPageApi =  axios.get('http://localhost:3005/search/', { params: { q: this.$route.query.search } }).then((res) => {
                    store.commit('frontPagePosts', res.data.tours.posts)
                    store.commit('routePageHead', res.data.head)
    
                    // console.log(res.data)
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
                return requestPageApi
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Gет параметры в атрибуте `this.$route.query`

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3005/search/', { params: { q: this.$route.query.search } }
```

в методе fetch доступен this, так что инъекция тут не особо нужна.

Проверил в своём проекте - роут есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно из-за инжекта `({store})` ... попробуй `({store, route})` и забрать `route.query`. Возможно из-за ssr - я его не использую.

Comment: Вернуло ошибку Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query') Я отредактирую вопрос и расшарю больше кода

Comment: звучит как вызов) сейчас проверю, поправлю если что

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное
Получилось достучаться до параметров таким образом store.app.context.query
Впринципе это подходит но подскажите есть ли метод не ходить по query циклом, для того чтобы вытащить параметры и сконкатенировать нужный запрос ?

Comment: `{params: this.$route.query}`